# C2886 class/struct typedef class self inheritance using

Tags: c++, class, struct, using

```
struct Foo
{
    typedef Foo FooInner;
};

struct Bar:Foo
{
    using Foo::FooInner;  // <-
};
```

// compiler: VS Express 2013 Update 1  - Compile Error C2886

// compiler: GCC 4.7.2 - Success

// Is it wrong?

Comment: Fyi, clang 3.3 has no issues with this either.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6f133eff.aspx) it is wrong for VS 2013.

"*'class::identifier' : symbol cannot be used in a member using-declaration
A **using** declaration uses a symbol, such as a namespace name. A **using** declaration is for declaring base class members.*"